# Upvote button on website with JavaScript, Php, AJAX, MySql not working. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax

I'm trying to create upvote/downvote buttons on a list of articles that I get from a MySql database. The buttons work in the sense that you press on the button and it gets the id of the article. However I can't get the id from article page to the php voting page. When I press the button the database doesn't register the vote. What am I doing wrong?

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {

    $(".vote").click(function() 
    {


    var id = $(this).attr("id");
    var name = $(this).attr("name");
    var dataString = 'id='+ id ;
    var parent = $(this);


    if(name=='up')
    {
      alert('you upvoted on '+ dataString);

    $(this).fadeIn(200);
    $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "weblectureupvote.php",
       data: dataString,
       cache: false,

       });

    }
    else
    {
    alert('you downvoted on '+ dataString);
    $(this).fadeIn(200);
    $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "weblectureupvote.php",
       data: dataString,
       cache: false,

     });
   }
    return false;
      });

    });
    </script>
```

This is the php file:

```
<?php

$pid = $_POST['id'];

try {



$db = new PDO('mysql:host=' . $config['db']['host'] . ';dbname=' . $config['db']['dbname'], $config['db']['username'], $config['db']['password']);
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);


$result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM database WHERE pid = '$pid' ") or die(mysql_error());

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        // temp user array
        $lecturelist = array();
        $lecturelist["pid"] = $row["pid"];
        $lecturelist["upvote"] = $row["upvote"];
        $lecturelist["downvote"] = $row["downvote"];
        $lecturelist["vote"] = $row["vote"];

      }



$upvote= $row["upvote"];
$downvote = $row["downvote"];
$vote = $row["vote"];
$upvote = $upvote + 1;


$query = $db->prepare('UPDATE database SET upvote = :upvote WHERE pid = :pid');
$query->execute(array(  
  ':upvote'  => $upvote,
  ':pid'    => $pid
)); 
$query = $db->prepare('UPDATE database SET vote=:vote  WHERE pid = :pid');
$query->execute(array(  
  ':vote'  => $vote,
  ':pid'    => $pid
)); 


} catch(PDOException $e) {
  echo $e->getMessage();
}
?>
```

Comment: For starters, where is the HTML tag that you think `$(".vote")` is going to select?

Comment: Can you provide more info? When you say "When I press the button the database doesn't register the vote." you don't give us much to work with.  Does the click handler on the `.vote` element get fired? Is the AJAX request being fired? Does the server respond? \

Comment: I didn't include that part but it works. `<div id="main">
<div class="box1">
<div class='up'><a href="" class="vote" id="<?php echo $pid; ?>" name="up">

<?php echo $up; ?></a></div>
<div class='down'><a href="" class="vote" id="<?php echo $pid; ?>" name="down">
  <?php echo $down; ?></a></div>
</div>

</div>`

Comment: @Steve the click handler on .vote gets fired, I am not sure if the AJAX request works or if the problem is on the php/mysql side. I suspect the dataString id element isn't sent to the php voting file.

Comment: Well, we can't do this debugging step for you.  You need to use the developer tools in your browser to see if the AJAX request gets send out and if so, what data it contains.  In Chrome, you would use the "Network" tab in your "Developer Toolbar" for that purpose

Comment: You're mixing `mysql_*` functions with PDO, **that's what's wrong.**

Comment: @Steve I did that and when I press the upvote button it gives 200
OK
text/html
jquery-1.11.0.min.js:4

Comment: OK... that's a good start... and did it have the correct data (i.e. `id=123`) in the request?

Comment: I'll give you a starting tip: You most likely need to use `$query = $db->prepare(" SELECT...` then  `$result=$query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);` instead of `$result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM database WHERE pid = '$pid' ")` and `while($row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))` or `PDO::FETCH_OBJ` etc. The rest I will leave up to you. @Jerome

Comment: Check out [**this PDO tutorial**](http://www.phpro.org/tutorials/Introduction-to-PHP-PDO.html) it's quite good and concise. That's the best advice I can give you right now. I've been coding all day and my eyes are literally in the same socket. If you have any problems, let me know and I'll see if I can be of help, can't promise you anything though. Good luck with that. @Jerome

Comment: You're welcome Jerome. Did you use some of my comments? Just curious.

Comment: I actually I realized what was wrong when you said you can't combine mysql_* with pdo, and then accessed the php file directly like tigan said which confirmed the line where the error was, was exactly the mysql_* issue you mentioned. After that I went to work and since I had a file from a different project which queried exclusively with PDO I only had to adapt a little. So by the time I came back to stackoverflow to see your second comment I had already fixed it.

Comment: Right on, well am glad this got resolved, cheers Jerome.

Answer (score 1):

```
data: {id: id}
```

this will get to your php file a "id" variable ( this is the first id ) and with some value ( from the second id )

now

```
$pid = $_POST['id'];
```

this should work, as you weren't sending "much" to the server

Comment: You need to go over OP's entire code, and [`see this`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23095617/upvote-button-on-website-with-javascript-php-ajax-mysql-not-working-what-am#comment35302337_23095617)

Comment: What you are suggesting is probably the better approach, but is essentially identical to what the OP is doing.  He is just doing the object to string translation himself instead of letting jQuery handle it for him.

Comment: I changed that and it didn't work so I think Fred is probably right but I am not sure how to fix the mysql_* part.

Comment: try accessing directly from your browser the .php file, comment out the part where you get the id from the form and "hard code" the id, now with small echo/print_r/var_dump and die step by step verify that your code does what it should

Comment: Not *probably*, but am (right). You can't mix `mysql_*` or any other API with PDO. @Jerome